# Why would a class with inherited constructors get a synthesized default constructor as well?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

**C++ Primer** (5th edition) on page 629 states:

> A class that contains only inherited constructors will have a synthesized default constructor.

What is the reasoning behind this rule?

Comment: If you inherit from default-constructible class, why shouldn't your derived class also be default constructible?

Comment: The question assumes that the base class defines only non-default constructors.

Answer (score 6):

I think that quote can be misgiving. The following, for example, will not compile:

```
struct Base{
    Base(int){}
};

struct Derived : Base{
    using Base::Base;
};

int main()
{
    Derived d; // error: Derived has no public default ctor!!!
}
```

`Derived` *contains only inherited constructors*, but it does not have a *public* default one! I said public! Actually, the error message from `gcc` is:

> 'Derived::Derived()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed

So, what the author means is that if a `Derived` class inherit constructors from a `Base` class, a default constructor for `Derived` will be provided, because it may have to default initialize `Derived`'s data member that can't be initialized from inherited constructors, because they even don't know of their existence.

Finally, in my example the default ctor for Derived has been implicitly deleted by the compiler, because no one explicitly defined it. But if you add a default ctor to Base, the synthesized default ctor for Derived will be available.

Comment: The other inherited constructors do default-initialize the data members of the derived class. Why can't an inherited default constructor do the same?

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg You're right! And you helped me to get the point. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Do you mean that all the inherited constructors call the synthesized default constructor of the derived class? If so, this still leaves a question: since the compiler knows that the data members of the base class will be initialized by the inherited constructors, what use is there for a default constructor of the base class?

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg To our purposes, a default ctor for Base would give the possibility to default construct Derived. Otherwise, how would Derived default construct Base?

Comment: It won't. There is no need to! The inherited constructors initialize all members of Base and that's all we need.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg In fact, the only point where Base default ctor is needed is if you want to define an actual public usable Derived default ctor

Comment: That's right. And I would request one with `=default` if I wanted one. My original question from which the post started thus stands...

Answer (score 2):

If the base class does not contain a constructor without parameters, then the compiler would not be able to generate a default constructor for the derived class because it needs the missing arguments for the constructors of the base class. However, if base class contains a default constructor or a constructor that does not take any parameters, then a default constructor for the derived class can be generated with the usual purpose of calling constructors of the member variables. The purpose is the convenience not to write an empty constructor yourself if the constructor doesn't do anything special.